# Dropwizard @NamedQuery parameters

Tags: java, dropwizard

I am using the dropwizard sample example and want to use a sql query that takes in parameters.

here my Namedquery in my User2 class

```
@NamedQuery(
            name = "com.example.helloworld.core.User2.name",
            query = "SELECT p FROM User2 p where p.name = :name"
        )
```

and in my User2Dao class I have this method.

```
public List<User2> findRole(String x) {
    return list(namedQuery("com.example.helloworld.core.User2.name").setString("role", x));
}
```

here my nethod in my resource class

```
  @GET
@Path("/{id}")
public List<User2> getUser(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    return  userDAO.findRole(id);
}
```

I get this error.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No session currently bound to execution context
```

It is possible to use a @NamedQuery that takes in parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the  UoW annotation to your resource method as mentioned in the [manual](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.0/docs/manual/hibernate.html#transactional-resource-methods)

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@UnitOfWork
public List<User2> getUser(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    return  userDAO.findRole(id);
}
```